# What are the general consequences of C++ properties through anonymously typed member structures

Tags: c++, syntax, properties

A while back while working on a small game I thought of a way to implement C# style properties in C++ through using anonymous types on member structures of classes.

The implementation would go something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define get_member(name, type, parent_t, property) (*reinterpret_cast<type*>((this - offsetoff(parent_t, property)) + offsetoff(parent_t, name)))

class foo {
  public:
  foo(int x) : _value(x)
  {}

  struct {

    int& operator= (const int&) = delete;
    operator int() const { return get_member(_value, int, foo, value); }
  } value;

  private:
  int _value;
};


int main(void) {
  foo f = foo(10);
  std::cout << f.value << '\n';
  f.value = 1; // ERROR
}
```

So the question goes: what are the considerations in scalability and compatibility? The obvious caveats are that classes using this feature have to be standard layout, as well as that private methods are difficult to call without extra boilerplate.

Comment: its not "untyped" as you write in the title. The type has no name, but you can give it one via an alias `using type_of_themeber = decltype( std::declval<foo>().value);`

Comment: `foo::value` is not untyped, the type is only anonymous

Comment: You're right, this is the word I was looking for. Corrected the title.

Comment: You'd need a `operator int&()` conversion operator to be able to assign to it, but it won't work implicitly. Add a `operator=(int)` to make assignment work implicitly.

Comment: Using `offsetof` and `reinterpret_cast` are both red flags. Are they really necessary? Is their use here really correct?

Comment: Since member structures do not have access to their enclosing class it is unfortunately more or less necessary to do some pointer arithmetic, especially in the case of private members since they're an extra layer of unaccessible.

Comment: doesn't compile for me https://godbolt.org/z/K983f7e1q

Comment: Just a general remark, trying to move concepts of one programming language to another is ususally sub-optimal. C++ and C# work in fundamentally different ways.  And working with preprocessor macros... meh. Then at least investigate C++ a bit more and learn how to work with function and class templates. reinterpret_cast on members that will not be simple pod types is sure to fail at some point.

Comment: Apart from the red flags of using a macro, `offsetof()`, and `reintepret_cast` (which might be  mitigated somewhat by using formal setters/getters)  your approach is not exactly scalable.   If you want a class with multiple named properties, you'll need to define a nested `struct` for each one.   In general, rather than trying to hack something up to make C++ code using your class look like C#, better to learn techniques that are properly supported by C++.

Comment: And in the end what is wrong with an explicit `void set_value(const type_t& value)` and/or 
 `void set_value(type_t&& value)` setter function?

Comment: Formal getters and setters are obviously the way to go for most purposes these 'properties' would fill in c++. However this question is mostly intended as a discussion on what exact considerations this specific kind of approach would have. Obviously this needs lots of boilerplate to work, but then again so do getters and setters. Mostly I was interested in learning a bit about how bad the abi of this approach would get, or perhaps if the pointer arithmetic and indirection would cause much noticable performance drag.

Comment: The approach has the obvious problem of unneeded data, code and complexity while classical getter is expected by everybody and inlined by compilers to direct access of member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design violates the priciple of least surprise. If I see the code

```
int x = bar.value;
bar.value = y;
```

I would not expect user defined code to be (potentially) executed here. Depending on what you do in the 'setter' and 'getter' this can be problematic.
You also cannot take the address of `value` (in a meaningful way). Since value tries to mimick an ordinary data member, this will also be surprising to users of your code.

Other aspects are also surprising. Consider the following example:

```
foo f = /* ... */;
auto value = foo.value;
std::cout << value << "\n";
```

This crashes at runtime (if you're lucky) because we created a copy of the `value` object. We did not invoke `operator int()` in the second line. And when we invoke `operator int()` in the third line, there is no `foo` object around the local copy of `value` and the `reinterpret_cast` in `operator int()` result in undefined behaviour.

I think the simplest way of exposing values of a class with invariants is this:

```
class foo {
public:
    int value() const { return m_value; }
    
    // If necessary! Often you don't need setters
    void setValue(int value) { m_value = value; }

private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Just go with it. Other people will be used to it and can work with it.

Another problem is, that every 'property' takes up at least one byte of storage in every `foo` object. Depending on how many of them you have, this can add up and make `foo` an unnecessary large object and introduce a performancy penalty.

Comment: I think its *at least* one byte, extra padding between a property and the next member variable will lead to more space being used

Comment: The properties approach is more of an experiment than anything serious, but still really interesting behavior with 'auto' taking the type of the struct instead of the implicit cast, perhaps there is a way to circumvent this (Again, for experimentation. Doing is learning)

Comment: @Miroaja you'd have to delete the copy, and assignment operators

Comment: Thanks! I've used c++ for a while. But I have a general distaste for auto so I stay away from it mostly

Comment: @Miroaja It's definitely fun and interesting to hack around with language features, but you should stay away from it when writing serious code :-)

Comment: *definitely* not putting this one in production, though I will keep it in mind if I want to cause mayhem one day

Comment: Since C++20 there is [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) to try to get around the wasted storage.

Comment: @Miroaja Use of `auto` is proliferating in C++ and seems to become a more important part of each successive version of C++. I'd recommend getting comfortable with it.